# Does Windows Server 2016/19 support SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

We are planning to upgrade our Windows Server from 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2016/19. We have SharePoint 2013 installed in the Server.Can anybody please let me know if Windows Server 2016/19 support SharePoint 2013. If Yes please let me know the impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the software requirement from Microsoft, Windows Server 2016 not supported SharePoint 2013 installation:

[image]

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0)

For Windows Server 2019, no official document specified, but I think still not supported for SharePoint 2013.